# Can a Jew drink wine of a ger toshav?

Tags: gentiles, avodah-zarah, noachide-laws, stam-yenam, ger-toshav

I've heard it said that a Jew cannot drink the wine of a non-Jew. Can a Jew drink the wine of a ger toshav?

It appears to me that the reason a Jew cannot drink from a non-Jew's wine is that it is assumed the non-Jew is an idolator. But what about the non-Jew who accepts upon himself the sheva mitzvot in the presence of a proper court and is judged as a ger toshav?

Comment: Note that a Ger Toshav (in all likelihood) hasn't existed for millenia. This is an interesting theoretical question, though

Comment: @DoubleAA What about Chasidei umot haOlam? Maybe I should repost it as that, but I'm not sure if ger toshav and chasidei umot haOlam are the same thing. Also, I'm not so sure if the ger toshav doesn't exist, however, they're just not accepted('ayin mkablin' as the Rambam puts it). I can't get a hold of the book(it's out of print), but I heard the Rogatchover Gaon had a similar opinion(that they exist, but just are not accepted).

Comment: See Rambam MA 11:7

Comment: Wow great find! I'd also suggest starting to read at halachah 5 and on, where it talks about the eved where it is permitted! Very interesting. Now I'll have to ask why, ha! I'll save that question for another day.

Comment: @EhevuTov Since an eved was actually misgayer with bris and mikvah and was mekabel ol malchus shamaim, but is chayav like a woman, then the full halachos of a goy do not apply to him. Note that when he is freed, he automatically becomes a full Jew.

Answer (score 4):

The quick answer is no.
In שו"ע יו"ד סימן קכ"ד סעיף ב the Shulchan Aruch says:

> גר תושב, דהיינו שקבל עליו שבע מצות, וכן גר שמל ולא טבל – מגען אוסר בשתייה

Ha-rav Leichtenstien claims that the שו"ע belives that it's not only a question of "What does this man do?" (an idolator), but rather "Who is he?". And that is why we can't drink wine that was opened even by a Ger that hasn't completed his process, and we know for sure that he isn't an idolator!

Here is a Shiur that disscusses this subject:
[Shiur by the VBM](http://www.etzion.org.il/vbm/archive/yomyom/dafyomyomi/2010-10-17.php)

Comment: Interesting. So this is in galus when ger toshav are not accepted and judged as not being an idolater.